# label over stat_function ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, label

I'm using ggplot2 on R and I'm trying to plot some functions. The thing is I'm trying to add a label over the colorful plot generated with  stat_function.

The only thing I found was to add the color on the legend, but I need to add the label over the functions not in the legend ( for the sake of my work ).

A sample code is provided below

```
library(ggplot2)
f <- ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0, 10)), aes(x))
f + stat_function(fun = sin, colour = "red") +
stat_function(fun = cos, colour = "blue")
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Would `geom_text()` be sufficient?

Comment: I don't know how I can add it on the stat_fun. 
I know that geom_text can add some labels , but the thing is that I need to specify the data, and in this case I don't know the Y ( it's some hard functions ) .
If you have some ideas , I'm in

Comment: Well, you can calculate y from your fun on the go `geom_text(x = x1, y = fun(x1), label = 'Fun foo')`. Mybe pacakge `ggrepel` could be of some assistance.

Comment: Hmmm I thought so, but I tried to get something already built in in ggplot.
Anyway thank you for your help !